# Send mouseclicks at coordinates

Tags: scripting, x11

I am currently utilizing a script to send mouse input to certain buttons like this:

```
xdotool mousemove <x> <y>
xdotool click --window <window_id>
```

This works fine, but it is annoying that the mouse has to be moved, since this interferes with doing other things manually.

Is it somehow possible under X to send clicks/mouse events at specified locations without moving the cursor?

Of course you can use `mousemove restore`, but this is a sub-optimal solution since the cursor is still being moved.

Comment: Use chaining, it's extremely fast, you won't notice any interference.
`xdotool mousemove 10 10 click 1 mousemove restore`

Comment: @IporSircer I am aware of that, but I definitely notice the interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late but if you add a really short sleep between click and restore to the chained command, the mouse is restored without noticing additional moves on my machine.

For example `xdotool mousemove <x> <y> click 1 sleep 0.01 mousemove restore`

I did notice a difference from using `sleep 0.1 vs sleep 0.01`, though the man page only covers 0.x fractions of seconds but as delay works in ms it would explain the difference.

Without sleep there is a noticeable delay between move and restore, which I can not explain.