# Sending a click event to an inactive window in linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, plasma

I'm trying to automate a task which involves clicking on a window in certain places at certain times, but I want to do other things in the meantime. Is there any tool that can send a click event to a particular coordinate to an *inactive* window?

I'm using the Plasma desktop environment on X11 on arch linux.

Comment: What is your programming language ?

Comment: @MC68020 Ideally python but I don't care about the language. If it works in C or java or bash or whatever I can use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, but the following answer sounds like it does exactly what you want:

[Send mouseclicks at coordinates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688743/282315)

> ...if you add a really short sleep between click and restore to the chained command, the mouse is restored without noticing additional moves on my machine.
>
> For example `xdotool mousemove <x> <y> click 1 sleep 0.01 mousemove restore`
>
> I did notice a difference from using `sleep 0.1` vs `sleep 0.01`, though the man page only covers 0.x fractions of seconds but as delay works in ms it would explain the difference.
>
> Without sleep there is a noticeable delay between move and restore, which I can not explain.

Comment: xdotool with the --window option is exactly what i needed. Thank you